# Notice: Array to string conversion -json response with doctrine

Tags: arrays, json, symfony

I want to put a response json after decoding it in database, 
my controller code is as follows:

```
$jsondata = "{\"employees\":[
    { \"lastName\":\"Doe\"},
    { \"lastName\":\"Smith\"},
    {\"lastName\":\"Jones\"}
]}";





$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);
//  var_dump($data['employees']);
$machinetags = $data['employees'];
if ($machinetags) {
    $machinetags = $em->getRepository('VCycleMachineTagsBundle:MachineTag')->findOrCreateByTitles($machinetags);
}
foreach($machinetags as $machinetag) {
    $photo->addMachineTag($machinetag);
}
$em->persist($photo);
$em->flush();
```

But when i run it, it gives me this error:

```
{
    "code": 500,
          "message": "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS  id_1, t0.title AS title_2, t0.created_at AS created_at_3 FROM machinetag t0 WHERE t0.title IN (?, ?, ?)' with params [[\"Doe\"], [\"Smith\"], [\"Jones\"]]:\n\nNotice: Array to string conversion"
}
```

hw to fix it please, such as $machinetags is an array

The function addMachine tag is as follows :

```
             public function addMachineTag(MachineTag $machinetag)
{
    $photoMachineTag = new PhotoMachineTag();
    $photoMachineTag->setMachineTag($machinetag);
    $photoMachineTag->setPhoto($this);
    $this->photoMachineTags->add($photoMachineTag);
}
```

Comment: can you post addMachineTag? your params should be : ["Doe", "Smith","Jones"]

Comment: Please post the contents of the findOrCreateByTitles method in your repository.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: foreach ($data['employees'] as $d)
 { 
$machinetags = $d;}   The problem is here, i want to put all items of $data['employees'] in $machinetags, how can i do that